# Facebook API key? Same as Application ID?

Tags: facebook

I've setup an application for my site via facebook & unlike other screenshots I have seen on the web where it shows an API key, I DO NOT have one.... all I have shown is "Application ID", followed by "Application Secret"..... so was wondering if the App ID is the same as the API key? As I am using the App ID with another WP plugin?

Comment: Note that you can no longer use an API key when calling certain features, most notably /dialog/oauth?client_id={api_key} ... you must now use App Id. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651469/error-500-after-todays-push-at-821 - I mention this because it means that API key and App ID are not "same" - in at least this case you *must* now use App Id, when Api Key used to be accepted in the past.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

APP ID, APP KEY and APP Secret are three different things.

APP ID is a unique number(integer) for each application on facebook.

The following URL [link](http://www.facebook.com/developers/)  should land you on your application dashboard page, where you can see all the application which you have created on facebook. After that, click on the application name which you have created recently and you should be see your application id, key, secret and other settings.

:)

#### UPDATED, PLEASE READ BELOW:

As of 2011 *APP ID* and *API KEY* is now the same value, and is listed as such under the label **App ID/API Key** on the app details and settings page.

Comment: Thanks..... yeah I was originally looking on the "Edit Settings/Web Site" part, where it didn't list it.... but when I just clicked on the site name it showed it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Your link to facebook.com/developers takes me to my new app page where there are two alpha numeric references only: 'App ID/API Key' and 'App Secret'. Further down there is an Access Token. Please confirm that your answer is still valid as of July, 2011.

Comment: yup, App ID and API Key are now the same.

Comment: @Paul Yes, the App Access Token is used for more in-depth OpenGraph manipulation, where the app is the one authenticating to OG. 

_In addition to obtaining User access tokens, it's possible to obtain App access tokens and Page access tokens. App and Page access tokens allow you to use the Graph API on behalf of an App or a Page in order to modify your application's properties, create test users or to read Insights data for example._ quoted from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

Answer (score 12):

App ID and API Key were different before. But since the introduction of the new Developer dashboard. They are now the same.

You now can use App ID where your code requires API Key.

Answer (score 3):

You can in fact still get an API key via public FQL query:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+app_id,api_key,+canvas_name,+display_name+from+application+where+app_id+%3D+'enterYourAppIdHere'

Answer (score 1):

You can still get the API Key.
Go to http://facebook.com/developers/apps.php
You can find API key, API ID and APP secret of your facebook apps.

Comment: not exactly. This is exactly where the two keys are now unified.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/.

You can see App ID and App Key is same and it is numeric and App Secret is associated with app key.

[image: fb key]