# Error 500 on dialog/oauth API after today's push at 8:21

Tags: facebook, oauth

Our apps are getting error 500 on this call :

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=89dc1edc0036d868930ccbac657e8b7f&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Frealmofempires%2F&scope=email

Does anyone know of any issues?

There is a work around, just replace the "www.facebook.com" with "m.facebook.com"

Comment: Are you guessing the change happened at Facebook at 8:21 based on when you started getting the error, or is there a way to see when Facebook publishes API changes?

Comment: Did you managed to fix this? I have this problem but the funny part is that it only does it for me in IE (all versions). Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Facebook seems to have dropped support for the old API KEYs. If you look at your App Settings page, you'll see App Id/Api Key. These were merged back in 2011, so just replace your api_key with your app_id for the client_id parameter.

This should have been a breaking change.

Comment: This was a lifesaver. Thanks Hal. How did you pick up this change went live today and was responsible for Greg's issue?

Comment: This change broke all of the places I was using FBC, so I started looking through the integration documentation and realized it said to use the app_id for the client_id parameter. Pretty sure the documentation changed and was not the case when when they first released oAuth, and surprised they disabled this without alerting us.

Comment: I agree I always feel at their mercy. I didnt see any mention of this change on the developer blog, etc. You saved me hours of work today, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem by removing all cookies at facebook.com and then visit your posted link.

If you visit http://www.facebook.com once, then your URL will work. If found it now needs a cookie at facebook.com to work (named datr at facebook.com). There must be a change/problem at facebook.

It also works if you visit the corresponding login.php directly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what oauth tool you're using, it's possible to get an error 500 if the API key and/or secret are missing